# I have error of adding this white screen, is there is anyway I can do that

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I used stack and `clipRRect` to `bordeerRadius`. but i need to get this white background. tell me the way I can do this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack 1. with Container to fill the image and 2. to show a container   like this.

Output: Checkout the output at [dartPad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f354e3999d0d5156597213a4058b6208&null_safety=true)

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Size get displayMetrics => MediaQuery.of(context).size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
      Container(
        width: displayMetrics.width,
        height: displayMetrics.height,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Image goes here',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ),
      ), // Add image.asset here to load image
      Container(
        width: displayMetrics.width,
        height: displayMetrics.height * 0.4,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(32), topRight: Radius.circular(32))),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Bottom widgets goes here',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4?.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```